# Online accounts login prompt is distorted on website pop-ups

Tags: login, email, settings, 21.04, online-accounts

When trying to login to an online account through the settings which opens a website pop-up (ex. Google, Microsoft, Flickr, and Foursquare) the popup is distorted and I can't see anything (see the following image).

[image: distorted website popup]

This happens on all the website authorization pop-ups (Google, Microsoft, Flickr) except Foursquare. It doesn't happen on authorization pop-ups which aren't websites (Ubuntu One, Microsoft Exchange, IMAP/SMTP, etc.) I have tried multiple restarts to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu v21 online adding Google account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382717/ubuntu-v21-online-adding-google-account). I had this issue on a fresh 22.04 Pi installation and the answer by Harold solved my problem and it will solve yours too I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of help, but, according to [this thread](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/solved-google-chrome-transparent-overlay-distorting-text.447987/), try disabling *Use hardware acceleration when available* under Google Chrome's *Settings* → *Advanced*.

Comment: It's actually an issue with Wayland and Webkit composition that is causing this. A simple `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center` in a terminal window pops open the Accounts section and solves the bug. What is most interesting to me is that this has existed since 21.04 (that we know of) yet in 22.04 it is still an issue. Surely Ubuntu dev team would have encountered this and dealt with this by now?